# Marketing Cloud - In Transactional SMS API, Not getting SmsNotSent events through the Event Notification Service

Tags: marketing-cloud

We are sending Transactional SMS Outbound messages. We created a webhook using the Event Notification Service API and registered a callback URL, verified the URL and Subscribed to the TransactionalSendEvents.SmsSent and TransactionalSendEvents.SmsNotSent for that CallbackId.

When I send SMS to a landline number I should have received an SmsNotSent event to the webhook/callbackURL. However I am not receiving one. Has anyone else experienced a similar issue.

Also, is it possible to reply back to a Transactional SMS message and capture the inbound message? do anyone have an example.

We don't want to use the MobileConnect

Comment: _When I send SMS to a landline number I should have received an SmsNotSent event_ - this is your assumption but in reality it depends on country, middleware and the carrier. For example: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133647-What-happens-when-I-attempt-to-send-messages-to-a-landline-

Comment: have you tried the SMS not sent with another use case eg invalid phone number?

Comment: Does it show as undelivered in smstracking dataview?

Comment: @NoorAlam - I tried sending to an 15555555555 (invalid phone number) in US. It shows SmsSent

Comment: @EazyE - I checked the smsmessagetracking data view. It shows both sent and delivered as true for invalid numbers.

Comment: SO until the carrier/aggregator report back that its undelivered it will show as delivered